# How to rename key/header in csv DictReader

Tags: python, csv, awk

For instance given `mycsv.csv` file

```
h1,h2
a,b
c,d
```

how to rename `h2` onto `HTwo` with `reader`

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('mycsv.csv'))
```

(Additionally how to write the csv file back with the updated header.)

**Note** approaches with awk are also valued.

Comment: Is that all you want to do?  I ask because `awk` would be a simpler solution.

Comment: @Brian awk is very valid for an answer especially if it proves simpler... thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple CSV file (one that contains no quoted strings), `awk` is a fine solution, and Brian's answer will work fine.  If your CSV file contains quoted strings that themselves contain commas, like this:

```
h1,h2
"this, is, value, 1",value2
```

...then `awk` will fall over.

If you want to do this in Python, there's no reason to use `DictReader`.  Something like this will work:

```
import csv

with open('mycsv.csv') as infd, open('mycsv.out', 'w') as outfd:
  reader = csv.reader(infd)
  writer = csv.writer(outfd)

  # read the header
  header = next(reader)

  # modify the column title
  header[1] = 'hTwo'

  # write the new header out
  writer.writerow(header)

  # copy all other rows unmodified
  for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)

# and then rename mycsv.out to mycsv.csv if you wish.
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve it is to use `pop()`

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('mycsv.csv'))

for d in reader:
   d['HTwo'] = d.pop('h2')
```

Answer (score 2):

awk oneliner:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1 && $2=="h2" {$2="hTwo"};1' file
```

The above is very specific: it says "if the first line contains 'h2' in the second field, change it to 'hTwo'"

Answer (score 1):

inplace replacement with `sed`

```
$ sed -i '1s/h2/HTwo/' mycsv.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSV DictReader:

Change headers of CSV file and copy the contents to another file:

```
import csv
with open('old_file.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    # read the orignal headers ["head1", "head2"]
    print("old headers list", reader.fieldnames)

    # set new_headers_list []
    new_headers_list = ["new_head1", "new_head2"]
    reader.fieldnames = new_headers_list

    rows = list(reader)
    with open("new_file", "w") as new_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=new_headers_list)
        # write the new header out
        writer.writeheader()
        # copy all other rows unmodified
        writer.writerows(rows)
```